# How do I make every node in my application have the focusTraversableProperty property as false by default?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application with many nodes in different windows. I want to make it so that the `focusTraversableProperty` is set to false on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try putting the following in an external style sheet:

```
.root, .root * {
    -fx-focus-traversable: false ;
}
```

With multiple windows, you will have to ensure this stylesheet is applied to all the scenes you create, but it will be much easier than applying settings to each node by hand.

Comment: That worked in a way but I noticed I can't use tab to go to cycle through the text-boxes, which should've been expected. In any case the css style does work but I've found out that disabling the traversable focus isn't what I wanted to do. Thanks though

Comment: Yes, that's what [`focusTraversable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty--) means: you can traverse the focus... What did you actually want to do?

Comment: I have a tableview and for some reason I didn't see the method that disables focusTraversable and I thought it was supposed to be done somewhere higher up.